# System doesn't function properly without hardware reserved memory

Tags: windows-7, memory, motherboard, bios

I've got a Foxconn Renaissance motherboard, and I'm using the newest supportable version of BIOS, 6GB memory, 2GB memory on my GTX760 graphics card, and WIndows 7 x64,

Unfortunately, there's no option to enable memory remapping, which is causing me a really strange problem. After about a week of fiddling with the settings, I've determined that the only way for my new graphics card to work is to truncate the memory in the bcdedit settings.

After trial and error I determined that truncating at in the memory address 0x12c9003ee (4.7GB) gives me exactly 4GB of memory available to Windows, and reserves exactly 2GB in the resource monitor under "Hardware Reserved". If I reserve any less the graphics card doesn't work well, and the whole system sputters and lags.

I assume this has something to do with poor memory mapping, because the graphics card works flawlessly but I'm not able to use those last 2GB of RAM.

Is there anything I can do given my BIOS does not support memory remapping? The motherboard can support upto 24GB or RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Launch `cmd` "As Administrator"

/1. Disable DEP protection:

Disable:

```
bcdedit.exe /set {current} nx AlwaysOff
```

Enable (restore default):

```
bcdedit.exe /set {current} nx AlwaysOn
```

Reboot need!

/2. Disable [HPET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Disable:

```
bcdedit /deletevalue useplatformclock
```

Enable (restore default):

```
bcdedit /set useplatformclock true
```

Reboot need!

/3. See crush and error - uninstall PhysX.

Reboot need.

/4. "Memory Hole Remapping" set Enable
[image: "Memory Hole Remapping" Enable]

/5.  Foxconn Renaissance BIOS

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the settings on the bcdedit! I didn't even have HPET so that's a plus. But I did uninstall PhyX, reboot, removed truncatememory settings, reboot and still 15 minute startup time.

Comment: At the moment everything is working well? Or you get an error?

Comment: Yeah everything is fine, except 2GB RAM is inaccessible

Comment: See video card settings at BIOS maybe reserved 2Gb memory to video. And type command `wmic os get Caption` output (run at `cmd`)

Comment: BIOS doesn't allow me to mess with that info =/ and the caption I get is "Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium"

Comment: @CayetanoGonçalves  "Memory Hole Remapping" set `Enable` in BIOS? If not - set `Enable`.

Comment: I wish I could. Bios doesn't have that option. I  going to contact foxconn

Comment: @CayetanoGonçalves Advanced Chipset Features > North Bridge Configuration > Memory Remap Feature - Enabled

Comment: Is that a custom BIOS? The screen where I have Advanced Chipset Features has no option for North Bridge Configuration. Mine looks like this. http://www.manualowl.com/m/Foxconn/Renaissance/Manual/297260?page=36 It also has no "Gladiator Bios" options.

Comment: @CayetanoGonçalves Foxconn set AMI BIOS. In AMI "Memory Remap Feature ". Type command `wmic BASEBOARD get Manufacturer, Product, SerialNumber, Version` output (run at `cmd`). As variant load default BIOS. But you need save all settings. OS may not load.